# How to get values from a ViewModel from another ViewModel. c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the values that were created in `createProduct()` from my MyClassViewModel.

I tried to inherit BaseViewModel and ProductViewModel to MyClassViewModel but C# doesn't support it.

Product class:

```
public class Product
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int serial { get; set; }
        public double price { get; set; }
    }
```

ProductViewModel class:

```
public class ProductViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public Product product { get; set; }

        public void createProduct()
        {
            product = new Product();
            product.name = "product name;
            product.serial = 0123456789;
            product.price = 13.98;
        }
    }
}
```

This is where I'm trying to access the values of `product` from ProductViewModel. I want to get those values that were created.

My Class:

```
public class MyClassViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public Product pro { get; set; }    

        public double getFromProduct()
        {
            return pro.price;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Edited question. Hope is more clear.

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: In MyClassViewModel, I'm trying to get the values from product that are in ProductViewModel.

Comment: How do you expect to get anything from pro.price if you never assign anything to pro? That's basic c# programming.

Comment: Can you show the code where you create instance from these classes and where you invoke methods on them?

Comment: Assume I assigned values to pro.

Comment: You should review the basics of object oriented programming. So better you ask about documentation maybe

Comment: Where/when is MyClassViewModel created? Is it from inside the ProductViewModel? If so pass product through to the MyClassViewModel when you create it. This would require you to either create a constructor that accepts a Product parameter or use a dot notation to assign product to pro.

Comment: @ lyz: can you recommend me a good book, I'm new to OOP.

Comment: Sign up at Lynda.com and watch videos of OOP as well as C#.

Comment: I found a work around but I'm not sure if it is the proper way to do it. In ProductViewModel; I created public static double pri = 0.0, and assigned product.Price to pri. In MyClassVideoModel, in getFromProduct(), I return ProductViewModel.pri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place it in session it can be easily accessed across ViewModel 
 `Session["Name"]=Adam`